# SailsJs Protecting Blueprints with Policies

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sails.js

I have a model: `api/models/Agency.js`

```
attributes: {

        // attributes for agency

        // One agency can have many owners
        owners: {

          collection: 'user',
          required: true,
          via: 'agencies'
        },

        employees: {

          collection:   'user',
          via:          'employer'
        }
    }
```

The model has a *many to many* relationship with Users; as many Users can own many Agencies.

I want to protect the Blueprint controller for Agency (`AgencyController.js`) with a *Policy* called `isOwner.js`; which makes sure the User is the owner of the Agency before allowing them to make an edit. I have based the policy on the example found in the [Sails.js docs](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/request-req/req-options/req-options-where), where I am trying to ensure the userId (found in the session) is the owner of the resource.

`api/policies/isOwner.js`:

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {

    var userId = req.session.passport.user;

    req.options.where = req.options.where || {};

    req.options.where.owners = userId;

    return next();

};
```

Then in my `config/policies.js` file I have added the following:

```
    AgencyController: {

          destroy:  ['isOwner'],
          update:   ['isOwner']
    },
```

This doesn't work. I think its because of the many to many relationship between the two models. My question is can I create a policy that can query a many to many relationship? Or is it only possible through a one to many relationship?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a way of nicely protecting the blueprint methods by a policy alone so I created a service that checked the user was the owner of the model, and then extended the update and destroy methods in my controller.

api/services/isOwner.js:

```
/**
 * Only allow access to models if they are the owner.
 * Assumes an attribute called owners on the model and assumes it has a relationship that can be queried through the
 * 'populate' waterline method.
 */
var actionUtil = require( 'sails/lib/hooks/blueprints/actionUtil' );
var _ = require( 'underscore' );

/**
 * @param req
 * @param res
 * @param is {function} called if the user is the owner
 * @param isnt {function} called if the user is not the owner. If not present will redirect 403 not authorised.
 */
module.exports = function isOwner( req, res, is, isnt ){

    var ownerEmail = req.options.where.owner;
    var Model = actionUtil.parseModel( req );

    isnt = isnt || res.forbidden;

    is = is || function(){

            sails.log.warn( 'No callback defined for isOwner' );
            res.ok();
        };


    Model.findOne({ id: req.params.id }).populate( 'owners' ).exec( function( error, model ){

        var canEdit = _.find( model.owners, function( owner ){

            return owner.email === ownerEmail;
        });

        canEdit ? is() : isnt();
    });
};
```

api/controllers/AgencyController.js:

```
var update = require( 'sails/lib/hooks/blueprints/actions/update' );
var isOwner = require( '../services/isOwner' );

module.exports = {

    /**
     * Override the default blueprint update behaviour so only the owner can update a record.
     *
     * @param req
     * @param res
     */
    update: function( req, res ){

        isOwner( req, res, update );
    }
};
```

Doesn't feel like the nicest way of doing it but it's the only way I could think of. Just thought I'd share it on here just incase someone comes across the same problem OR someone has a better solution.